# Why are both "import logging" and "import logging.config" needed?

Tags: python, logging, import, python-logging

Should it not be handled by a single import? i.e. `import logging`.

If I do not include `import logging.config` in my script, it gives:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'config'

Answer (score 79, accepted):

`logging` is a package. Modules in packages aren't imported until you (or something in your program) imports them. You don't need both `import logging` and `import logging.config` though: just `import logging.config` will make the name `logging` available already.

Comment: Can you explain HOW does importing logging.config automatically make logging available as well?

Comment: I recommend you look at David Beazley's [deep dive](http://www.dabeaz.com/modulepackage/index.html) into Python's import routine, @crusarovid. That's how I learned the ugly details.

Comment: I took a look at David Beazley's deep Dive as Don Kirkby suggested. It's very long, and the answer to this particular issue is not easy to find therein. I'd just treat it as a brute fact that if you import a package's submodule (e.g. `logging.config`) then you also import the contents of the package's `__init__.py` file. In this case `config` from [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Lib/logging)

Answer (score 2):

Just add an addtional explanation for Thomas's answer.

`logging` is a package, a directory.

enter the logging dir and list what files there is:

`config.py  handlers.py  __init__.py  __pycache__`

so, There is a `config.py` file in logging directory, but why it can't `import logging.config`. That's because there is no `config` namespace in  `logging/__init__.py`